# Get a list of all registered objects implementing a certain interface

Tags: autofac

Consider the following

```
builder.Register(c => new A());
builder.Register(c => new B());
builder.Register(c => new C());
```

`B` and `C` are both `ISomeInterface`.

I would now like to get an `IEnumerable` of all registered objects that implement `ISomeInterface`.

How can I accomplish this in Autofac?

Comment: Autofac doesn't really support doing what you're asking. If you can't change the registrations, you might be hosed. Doing any queries against the collection of registrations doesn't necessarily take into account dynamic registration sources (some of which are automatically registered in the container - to support things like `IEnumerable<T>`). What you get out of the query may not be a complete list.

Answer (score 33, accepted):

Just tried this, works and does not depend on lifetime context:

Enumerate types using Activator instead

```
var types = con.ComponentRegistry.Registrations
     .Where(r => typeof(ISomeInterface).IsAssignableFrom(r.Activator.LimitType))
     .Select(r => r.Activator.LimitType);
```

Then to resolve:

```
IEnumerable<ISomeInterface> lst = types.Select(t => con.Resolve(t) as ISomeInterface);
```

Comment: Nice. Cleaner than my implementation.

Answer (score 31):

If you have

```
container.Register(c => new A()).As<ISomeInterface>();
container.Register(c => new B()).As<ISomeInterface>();
```

Then when you do

```
var classes = container.Resolve<IEnumerable<ISomeInterface>>();
```

You will get a variable that is a list of ISomeInterface, containing A and B

Comment: This doesn't work. The components are not registered as `ISomeInterface`, but implement them none the less.

Comment: Can you not do: container.Register(c => new SomeClassA()).As<ISomeInterface>()?

Comment: Unfortunately not, no. The actual registration is not under my control.

Comment: I'm not sure. That's how I get a list of the implementations back. Not sure what an alternative is...

Comment: what type is the container instance ?

Comment: `ILifetimeScope` or `IContainer` (or any of the other interfaces that are within the same chain

Answer (score 5):

Here is how I did it.

```
var l = Container.ComponentRegistry.Registrations
          .SelectMany(x => x.Services)
          .OfType<IServiceWithType>()
          .Where(x => 
                 x.ServiceType.GetInterface(typeof(ISomeInterface).Name) != null)
          .Select(c => (ISomeInterface) c.ServiceType);
```

Comment: This doesn't work for me - fails at the `Select` clause with `System.InvalidCastException: 'Unable to cast object of type 'System.RuntimeType' to type 'MyCompany.Communications.Core.ICommunicationService'.'`.

Answer (score 3):

I was looking for a similar solution for registrations done as follows:

```cs
builder.RegisterType<Bamboo>().As<IExoticTree>();
// and/or
builder.RegisterType<SolidOak>().Keyed<IMountainTree>(key);
```

where `IExoticTree` and `IMountainTree` inherit from a common `ITree` interface.

With those, the service type (e.g. registered interface) is different from the `LimitType` and hence, the proposed solution is not applicable.

I got inspired by the accepted solution to manage these as well with the following code:

```cs
IEnumerable<ITree> instances = scope.ComponentRegistry.Registrations
                                                      .Where(r => typeof(ITree).IsAssignableFrom(r.Activator.LimitType))
                                                      .Select(r => r.Services.First())
                                                      .Select(s => scope.ResolveService(s) as ITree)
                                                      .Distinct();
```

Hope it helps someone ^^

Comment: Very helpful and exactly what I was looking for... the accepted answer below doesn't work because the `r.Activator.LimitType` results in `Type` and is often too specific and may not be resolved for an Interface, whereby the `r.Services.First()` here works as expected resolving based on the registered type or interface, etc.

Answer (score 2):

I needed to resolve based on some context.  So slight variation...

```
 builder.RegisterAssemblyTypes(Assembly.GetAssembly(typeof(ISomeStrategy)))
   .Where(t => typeof(ISomeStrategy).IsAssignableFrom(t))
   .AsSelf();

 builder.Register<Func<SomeEnum, ISomeStrategy>>(c =>
 {
    var types = c.ComponentRegistry.Registrations
      .Where(r => typeof(ISomeStrategy).IsAssignableFrom(r.Activator.LimitType))
      .Select(r => r.Activator.LimitType);

    ISomeStrategy[] lst = types.Select(t => c.Resolve(t) as ISomeStrategy).ToArray();

    return (someEnum) =>
    {
      return lst.FirstOrDefault(x => x.CanProcess(someEnum));
    };
 });
```

Then for your class using the strategy

```
 public SomeProvider(Func<SomeType, ISomeStrategy> someFactory)
 {
    _someFactory = someFactory;
 }

 public void DoSomething(SomeType someType)
 {
    var strategy = _someFactory(someType);
    strategy.DoIt();
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

Clarification for any one searching this with regards to Inherited Class

Ex :

```
    public static IEnumerable<Type> GetTypesInherit<T>(this Assembly assembly)
    {
        var types = assembly.GetTypes()
            .Where(myType => myType.IsClass && !myType.IsAbstract && myType.IsSubclassOf(typeof(T)))
            .ToList();

        return types;
    }
```

Installer :

```
    public static IContainer Install()
    {
        var builder = new ContainerBuilder();
        var executingAssembly = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly();

        var testScreens = executingAssembly.GetTypesInherit<TestScreen>();
        foreach (var testScreen in testScreens)
        {                   
            builder.RegisterType(testScreen).As<TestScreen>();
        }

        var container = builder.Build();
        return container;
    }
```

Usage (Implicit) :

```
  public class MainViewModel(IEnumerable<TestScreen> testScreens) 
  {}
```

Comment: You could have more than one assembly.