# resolve all given the Type

Tags: autofac

From the [Autofac documentation](http://autofac.readthedocs.org/en/latest/resolve/relationships.html?highlight=ienumerable#enumeration-ienumerable-b-ilist-b-icollection-b) I can see how to get all registrations for a class T:

```
public T[] ResolveAll<T>()
{
  return _container.Resolve<IEnumerable<T>>().ToArray();
}
```

But when I only have the Type available, how can I get the equivalent results?

```
public Array ResolveAll(Type service)
{
  return _container.Resolve( ??? 
}
```

I am trying to implement a wrapper class which has a pre-defined interface.

---

EDIT

For quick reference, the answer from Matthew Watson (with relevant ideas from David L) is:

```
public Array ResolveAll(Type service)
{
    var typeToResolve = typeof(IEnumerable<>).MakeGenericType(service);
    return _container.Resolve(typeToResolve) as Array;    
}
```

Comment: Please see ["Should questions include “tags” in their titles?"](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/should-questions-include-tags-in-their-titles), where the consensus is "no, they should not"!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Get a list of all registered objects implementing a certain interface](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24369861/get-a-list-of-all-registered-objects-implementing-a-certain-interface)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is an example. I've added asserts to prove that the types returned from `ResolveAll<T>(this IContainer self)` are the same (and in the same order) as those returned from `ResolveAll(this IContainer self, Type type)`:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Linq;
using Autofac;
using Autofac.Core;

namespace AutofacTrial
{
    public abstract class Base
    {
        public abstract string Name { get; }

        public override string ToString()
        {
            return Name;
        }
    }

    public sealed class Derived1: Base
    {
        public override string Name
        {
            get
            {
                return "Derived1";
            }
        }
    }

    public sealed class Derived2: Base
    {
        public override string Name
        {
            get
            {
                return "Derived2";
            }
        }
    }

    public sealed class Derived3: Base
    {
        public override string Name
        {
            get
            {
                return "Derived3";
            }
        }
    }

    static class Program
    {
        static void Main()
        {
            var builder = new ContainerBuilder();

            builder.RegisterType<Derived1>().As<Base>();
            builder.RegisterType<Derived2>().As<Base>();
            builder.RegisterType<Derived3>().As<Base>();

            var container = builder.Build();

            var array1 = container.ResolveAll(typeof(Base));
            var array2 = container.ResolveAll<Base>();

            Trace.Assert(array1.Length == 3);
            Trace.Assert(array2.Length == 3);

            for (int i = 0; i < array1.Length; ++i)
            {
                Trace.Assert(array1[i].GetType() == array2[i].GetType());
                Console.WriteLine(array1[i]);
            }
        }

        public static T[] ResolveAll<T>(this IContainer self)
        {
            return self.Resolve<IEnumerable<T>>().ToArray();
        }

        public static object[] ResolveAll(this IContainer self, Type type)
        {
            Type enumerableOfType = typeof(IEnumerable<>).MakeGenericType(type);
            return (object[]) self.ResolveService(new TypedService(enumerableOfType));
        }
    }
}
```

**The underling implementation is the same**

I also used `Reflector` to look at the implementation of `Resolve<IEnumerable<T>>()`, and it winds up doing this:

```
public static TService Resolve<TService>(this IComponentContext context, IEnumerable<Parameter> parameters)
{
    return (TService) context.Resolve(typeof(TService), parameters);
}
```

which calls:

```
public static object Resolve(this IComponentContext context, Type serviceType, IEnumerable<Parameter> parameters)
{
    return context.ResolveService(new TypedService(serviceType), parameters);
}
```

So the two *must* be equivalent, since they are implemented that way.

Comment: Is this not equivalent to `_container.Resolve<IEnumerable<IProduct>>()`?  Might be missing something, but I'm trying to work out how to get all registrations when all I have is a Type.

Comment: @Steve Did you try it? The code I posted will return an `Array` with two resolved objects, one of type `NonPerishableProduct` and the other of type `PerishableProduct` - i.e., all the resolvable concrete classes that implement `IProduct`. Is that not what you wanted?

Comment: @Steve I added a simplified example that proves that it *is* equivalent.

Comment: Thanks for the answer @Matthew but in your edit, the method `ResolveAll(this IContainer self, Type type)` just ignores the `type` parameter and hard-codes `Base`as the type to be resolved. So it is equivalent to what I can already do, as you say, but doesn't help answer the question. Dave L has proposed using reflection, which may (surprisingly) be the best way.

Comment: @Steve Oops, yes - I'll just fix that.

Comment: @Steve There we go. I fixed it by adding the missing `Type enumerableOfType = typeof (IEnumerable<>).MakeGenericType(type);`

Answer (score 1):

You can invoke _container.Resolve by calling your wrapped method via reflection ([MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reflection.methodinfo.makegenericmethod.aspx)), but in doing so you will lose your compile-time type safety.

```
public class Container
{
    public T[] ResolveAll<T>()
    {
        return _container.Resolve<IEnumerable<T>>().ToArray();
    }

    public object ResolveAllGeneric(Type t)
    {
        MethodInfo method = GetType().GetMethod("ResolveAll")
                             .MakeGenericMethod(new Type[] { t });
        return method.Invoke(this, new object[] { });
    } 
}
```