# Autofac. Retrieve all services registered as named

Tags: c#, .net, inversion-of-control, autofac, ioc-container

I am trying to use named registration in the program. But example from documentation does not work.
http://autofac.readthedocs.org/en/latest/advanced/keyed-services.html#named-services

```
public class DbLoggerModule : Autofac.Module
{
protected override void Load(Autofac.ContainerBuilder builder)
{
builder.Register<DbLogger>().Named<ILogger>("1");
}
```

and got compilation error: No overload for method 'Register' takes 0 arguments

I also tried the following variants:

```
builder.RegisterType<DbLogger>().Named<ILogger>("1");
builder.RegisterType<DbLogger>().Named<ILogger>("1").As<ILogger>();
builder.RegisterType<DbLogger>().Named<ILogger>("1").As<ILogger>();
builder.RegisterType<DbLogger>().As<ILogger>().Named<ILogger>("1");
```

They do not cause a compile error.
But as it is not impossible to obtain a given named service:

1. var lll = _сontainer.ResolveNamed< ILogger >("1");

throws an exception: 
*The requested service '1 (Console1.ILogger)' has not been registered. To avoid this exception, either register a component to provide the service, check for service registration using IsRegistered(), or use the ResolveOptional() method to resolve an optional dependency.*

2. IEnumerable loggers = 
   _сontainer.Resolve< IEnumerable< ILogger > >();

Returns an empty list

**UPDATE**

Part of the problem was solved. During the experiments, I have created a few interfaces with similar names. As a result, I register one interface, but resolved other.

Now this line is working:

```
var lll = _сontainer.ResolveNamed< ILogger >("1");
```

However, I can not get a complete list of classes that implement the interface:

```
var lll = _сontainer.ResolveNamed<ILogger>("1");
lll.Log(null);   // working !
IEnumerable< ILogger >loggers=_сontainer.Resolve<IEnumerable< ILogger >>();// It returns an empty list
```

**ALSO**

When I refuse to named services, the programm begins to work:

```
builder.RegisterType<DbLogger>().As<ILogger>();
...
_сontainer.Resolve<IEnumerable<ILogger>>(); // working !
```

I suspect that we can not get a list of services registered as named.
Someone can confirm this?

**UPDATE 2**
Here is a very simple but complete example. It does not work. Why ?

```
public interface ISimpleService
{
    string Test();
}
public class SimpleService1 : ISimpleService
{
    public string Test()
    {
        return "Hello World from SimpleService1";
    }
}

internal class Program
{
    private static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var builder = new ContainerBuilder();
        {
            builder.RegisterType<SimpleService1>().Named<ISimpleService>("fff");
        }

        IContainer container = builder.Build();

        var services = container.Resolve<IEnumerable<ISimpleService>>();

        Console.WriteLine(services.Count()); // 0. Why ?
    }
}
```

Comment: Odd.  builder.RegisterType<DbLogger>().Named<ILogger>("1") should work.  Is your DbLoggerModule being called?

Comment: It should works. Is your module loaded in your container builder ? has `_container` been built before the registration of your component ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are trying to resolve ISimpleService (interface), but SimpleService1 registered only as class (because the named registration), not as interface.

Try this:

```
builder.RegisterType<SimpleService1>().Named<ISimpleService>("fff").As<ISimpleService>();
```

or

```
builder.RegisterType<SimpleService1>().Named<ISimpleService>("fff").AsImplementedInterfaces();
```

A fully working example:

```
public interface ISimpleService
    {
        string Test();
    }
    public class SimpleService1 : ISimpleService
    {
        public string Test()
        {
            return "Hello World from SimpleService1";
        }
    }

    internal class Program
    {
        private static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var builder = new ContainerBuilder();
            {
                builder.RegisterType<SimpleService1>().Named<ISimpleService>("fff").As<ISimpleService>();
            }

            IContainer container = builder.Build();

            var services = container.Resolve<IEnumerable<ISimpleService>>();

            Console.WriteLine(services.Count()); // 1.
        }
    }
```

Initial sample will work if resolve ISimpleService by name:

```
var services = container.ResolveNamed<IEnumerable<ISimpleService>>("fff");
```

Comment: It seems that, with this registration, the component of that `IEnumerable<ISimpleService> services` differs from a component resolved by that name `context.ResolveNamed<ISimpleService>("fff")` unless you supply `.SingleInstance()` to your registration.

Comment: Is this a bug? The documentation states "Services can be further identified using a service name. Using this technique, the Named() registration method replaces As()." https://autofaccn.readthedocs.io/en/latest/advanced/keyed-services.html#named-services

Answer (score 2):

If you want to resolve a list of named (and only those, no the ones registered with a name and without, as suggested in other answers), here is what you can do:

```
builder.RegisterType<Foo>().Named<IFoo>("IFoo").SingleInstance();
builder.RegisterType<Foo2>().Named<IFoo>("IFoo").SingleInstance();
builder.RegisterType<Foo3>().Named<IFoo>("2").As<IFoo>().SingleInstance();

var container = builder.Build();

//Will resolve type Foo2
var foo = container.ResolveNamed<IFoo>("IFoo");

//Will resolve 2 IFoo: Foo and Foo2
var foos = container.ResolveNamed<IEnumerable<IFoo>>("IFoo");
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code should work.

Are you sure you have registered your module in your container?

Ensure something like this when bootstrapping your container (assembly scanning or plain registration):

```
// This example being fx a console app    
containerBuilder.RegisterAssemblyModules(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly());

// Basic registration    
containerBuilder.RegisterModule<LoggerModule>();

// Ensure the container is build
_container = containerBuilder.Build();
```

Comment: Okay, so in example two, you need to call the ResolvedNamed method.. That's your error, then you will get a collection of 1.

Comment: I need to get a complete list of all services (registered as named) that implement the interface.
I can not use ResolveNamed since it requires the name.

    var services1 = container.ResolveNamed<IEnumerable<ISimpleService>>( ?? );

Maybe I did not understand you. Can you give an example of a method call?

Comment: Yes, please look at the following question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24369861/get-a-list-of-all-registered-objects-implementing-a-certain-interface

Comment: But we are completely losing named services ?
If we refuses the named services, we can get all the objects, implemented the interface, through the Resolve <IEnumerable <ISimpleService >> !

Comment: Well named services imply you want a specific implementation. Fx, a ConsoleLogger at a specific point.

When resolving by interface you want all implementations. This could be a range of validation or businessrules. 

Case being, what is the reallife scenario ?

Comment: reallife scenario: In autofac registered several subsystems on startup via plugin system. Subsystems are registered by a unique names. I need to get the subsystem by uniq name, and perform some work.

Comment: And they all share a common subset? If so, why not define a subsystem by modules, injecting them within the correct context ? 

Furthermore, this question also seems to be an issue of correct OO-design.

Another option would be keyed services, AutoFac also provides this option.

I would look into this article: http://docs.autofac.org/en/latest/faq/select-by-context.html

Comment: I'll look for other solutions. However, I really hope to find a solution to my current problem!

Comment: Also.I need to call subsystem is not only one of their names, but also to get them ALL and call interface method. To do this, I need to get all of the services that implement the interface. Not only one !

Comment: Could you give som example of how you're thinking this ? If you know the "contract" upfront, there should be no issue.