# Autofac resolve list of Types of registered components

Tags: c#, autofac

Is it possible to register components as a type, and later on get a list of all their types?

Meaning:

```
public abstract class MyObject
{
    ..
}

public class object1 : MyObject {}
public class object2 : MyObject {}
public class object3 : MyObject {}
public class object4 : MyObject {}

public class Root : IRoot
{
    public Root(IObjectsHolder objectsHolder)
}

public class ObjectsHolder  : IObjectsHolder
{
    // This list should contain: (typeof(object1), typeof(object2))
    public ObjectsHolder(List<Type> AllTypesThatInheritMyObject)
}

builder.RegisterType<object1>().As(context => context.Resolve<IObjectsHolder>().Deserialize<object1>().InstancePerlifetimeScope();
builder.RegisterType<object2>().As(context => context.Resolve<IObjectsHolder>().Deserialize<object2>().InstancePerlifetimeScope();


builder.RegisterType<Root>().As<IRoot>().SingleInstance();
builder.RegisterType<ObjectsHolder>().As<IObjectsHolder>().SingleInstance();

var container builder.Build();

container.Resolve<IRoot>();
```

I want to register all MyObjects inheritances in a way so that ObjectsHolder will get a list of their types. Is this possible somehow?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Get a list of all registered objects implementing a certain interface](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24369861/get-a-list-of-all-registered-objects-implementing-a-certain-interface)

Comment: Not really the same because I want the types, not the actual objects, and I want it to be resolved when resolving the Root

Comment: Why would you want that ? What are you trying to do ?

Comment: My objects holder needs a dictionary of all the conifguration objects with types as keys. Those are types that I deserialize from files, so I don't need to instaniate them

Comment: All of autofac's registrations can be found in `IContainer.ComponentRegistry.Registrations` and `ILifetimeScope.ComponentRegistry.Registration`. I suggest debugging to see if there's a way how to retrieve your info from there.

Comment: It is not quite clear for me, what you are trying to achieve...Using Dependecy Injection does not mean you have to abstract every type and use injection for everything. If you do not instantiate *objectX* types, but you need their types, there is no need to register them within controller. You can simply retrieve them using reflection and then use deserialization.

Comment: I do instinate them later on with the dependency later on by using the ObjectsHolder.Deserialize as I added in the above edited. These objects are anyway registered in the container and so I thought that maybe there is a way to get their types from the container instead of doing heavy reflection - see the edit, registrations changed to current state