# Autofac resolve all implementations of generic interface registered from assembly

Tags: c#, autofac, .net-6.0

I have some interface

```
public interface IConsumerHandler<T> where T : ISpecificRecord
{
    string TopicName { get; set; }
    event EventHandler MessageObtained;
    void OnMessageObtained(GenericEventArgs<T> e);
}
```

in app is object implementing this interface, but there will be much more like this in the future

```
ublic class ConsumerHandler1 : IConsumerHandler<CreateSubscription>
{
    public ConsumerHandler1()
    {
        MessageObtained += DataObtained;
    }

    public string TopicName { get; set; } = "subscription-ms-insert";

    public event EventHandler MessageObtained = delegate { };

    public void OnMessageObtained(GenericEventArgs<CreateSubscription> e)
    {
        var handler = MessageObtained;
        handler?.Invoke(this, e);
    }

    private static void DataObtained(object? sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        var args = (GenericEventArgs<CreateSubscription>)e;
        Console.WriteLine(args.Data);
    }
}
```

registered are as follows

```
builder.RegisterAssemblyTypes(assemblies)
       .AsClosedTypesOf(typeof(IConsumerHandler<>))
       .AsImplementedInterfaces();
```

Is there a way in autofac to obtain `IEnumerable<IConsumerHandler<ISpecificRecord>>` in service?

I can obtain `IConsumerHandler<CreateSubscription>`, but i want enumerable of all these handlers.

`CreateSubscription` is AVRO generated object, so it implements `ISpecificRecord`

Comment: check this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/24389885/12576990

Comment: @Rafael this approach doesn't work since I need to manage generic interface.. Or there is no described way how to do it for generic

Comment: Are you trying to get `IEnumerable<IConsumerHandler<ISpecificRecord>>` that includes `IConsumerHandler<CreateSubscription>`? That might be the problem. You can't cast `IConsumerHandler<CreateSubscription>` as `ConsumerHandler<ISpecificRecord>`.

Comment: And is there any way how to make this real?

Comment: You should check for covariance and contravariance https://autofac.readthedocs.io/en/latest/advanced/registration-sources.html#contravariant-registration-source